# Python web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to break a certain script into couple of functions, and I ended up with an error of "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

I tried to find how to fix it, but I end up in the same place.
This is the original script:

```
#setting query
query = "stroke"

#handleing white spaces
search = query.replace(' ', '+')

#setting results
results = 20

#setting the full url
url = (f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search}&num={results}")

#empty list for links
link_list = []

#scraping google
requests_results = requests.get(url)
soup_link = bs(requests_results.content, "html.parser")
links = soup_link.find_all("a")


#for each link in soup checking
for link in links:
    link_href = link.get('href')
    if "url?q=" in link_href and not "webcache" in link_href:
        title = link.find_all('h3')
        if len(title) > 0:
            full_link = link.get('href').split("?q=")[1].split("&sa=U")[0]
            link_list.append(full_link)
            print(full_link)
            print(title[0].getText())
            print("------")
```

This is the output:
[image]

It runs perfectly.
The idea is to take the query, change it to a list of phrases I want, and getting the same end result formation, for each query.

So I broke the code to couple of functions, and the last one gives me the error. Below is the code:

```
query_list = ['Coronary artery disease','Stroke','Diabetes mellitus','Alzheimer','Lower respiratory infections',\
              'Lung cancer','Cirrhosis']
query_list
```

First function:

```
def getting_links_func (queries):
    url_list = []

    #setting query
    func_queries = queries   

    #setting results
    results = 10
    
    for query in func_queries:
        #handleing white spaces
        search = query.replace(' ', '+')
        
        
        #setting the full url
        url = (f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search}&num={results}")

        #update list with links
        url_list.append(url)
    
    return url_list
```

output:
[image]

second function:

```
def links_soup_func (url_list):
    soup_list = []
    
    
    for url in url_list:
    #scraping google
        requests_results = requests.get(url)
        soup_link = bs(requests_results.content, "html.parser")
        links = soup_link.find_all("a")
        soup_list.append(links)
        
    
    return soup_list
```

seems to work well:
[image]

the third function is the naughty one:

```
def urls_from_soup_func (soup_list):
    #for each soup getting the links in the search page
        for soup in soup_list:           
            link_href = soup.get('href')           
            if "url?q=" in link_href and not "webcache" in link_href:
                title = soup.find_all('h3')
                if len(title) > 0:
                    full_link = soup.get('href').split("?q=")[1].split("&sa=U")[0]
                    link_list.append(full_link)
                    print(full_link)
                    print(title[0].getText())
                    print("------")
```

here I'm getting the find or find all error. I tried playing around, breaking the for loop and checking just for one item, but I keep getting to the same issue.

[image]

I hope I explained myself well.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. You are appending the `ResultSet` object to your list, instead of extending it with single `<a>` elements.

```py
# what you are doing is this
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
a.append(b)
print(a)  # [1, 2, [3, 4]]

# you should be doing this
a.extend(b)
print(a)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Below change should solve your problem.

```py
soup_list.extend(links)
```